# How do I remove the terrain checkbox from Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

I don't mind having the map/satellite options, but I don't need the terrain option for my map. How do I disable just that? I don't see it documented well on

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls

Answer (score 2):

Your map object should contain MapTypeControlOptions and MapTypeIds, where you can control what options to show, for example the code below suppresses the **terrain**:

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {lat: 40, lng: 30},
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {      
      mapTypeIds: [
        google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
      ]
    }
  });
}
```